# Minute give wrong values on substract

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to subtract minutes and get the difference. below is my code

```
 double diff = currBlock.EndTime.Subtract(currBlock.StartTime).TotalMinutes;
```

In given code (currBlock.StartTime = 23:30:00) and (currBlock.EndTime= 00:20:00)
here starttime is time of today i.e.(09/26/2016 23:30:00), night time which will be consider as 11:30 PM and endtime is time of tomorrow i.e.(09/27/2016 00:20:00), morning time which will be consider as 12:20 Am. In my code i am getting values in minus which is -1390 and it is incorrect. So please help me to solve this.

Here i have attach image of data for further reference. [image]

Comment: You use DateTime or DateTimeOffset ? If second one - you probably have regional time offset from UTC representation and it will cause the error you see. Could you provide completed test case?

Comment: Specify the Type for EndTime and StartTime. You need DateTime here.

Comment: Show code, with create and fill `currBlock`

Comment: You're most likely subtracting `TimeSpan`s, if date is a factor, then you need to include that in the calculation, by using either `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: @eocron06 i am getting this data from database, so no idea about that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt please explain me properly, how do i use it? it is just a time block for different shift so there is no date include in it.

Comment: why is it wrong ? according to your code 23:30 is 1410 minutes and when you subtract 20-1410 the answer is -1390.What are you expecting? There is no mention of date here.

Comment: @Rohit please see all details, here 00:20 is next day time and 23:30 is today time so it should come in positive value i.e 50 minutes

Comment: @Developer Yes I can read that but to make your code work you need to explain this same fact to your code as well.

Comment: All you need is the knowledge that end > start, so when end-start is negative just add 24*60.

Answer (score 2):

> please explain me properly, how do i use it? it is just a time block for different shift so there is no date include in it

There *is* a date included in it. You're telling us that `EndTime` is something like 09/27/2016 00:20:00, while `StartTime` is something like 09/26/2016 23:30:00. The problem is that that knowledge is *in your head and not in your code*. If you subtract the values as `TimeSpan`s, then you're literally saying: what is 30 minutes minus 23 hours and 30 minutes. The answer, of course is -23 hours. To get the real difference, you *must* include the dates, which means utilizing a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` type for both `StartTime` and `EndTime`, so you can encode that whole date and time. Then, when you do the subtraction, it will return the right value.

Answer (score -1):

Below Code works for me. Thanks friends for your support and help.

```
string strCurrDate = (DateTime.Now.Date + currBlock.EndTime).ToString();
                        DateTime dtYourDate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date + currBlock.StartTime).ToString());
                        string strYourDate = dtYourDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + dtYourDate.ToLongTimeString();
                        string strTotalMinsElapsed = TotalMinutesElapsed(dtYourDate).ToString();



 private long TotalMinutesElapsed(DateTime dtYourDate)
        {
            long lTotalMinutesElapsed = 0;

            //Find Current Date and Time
            DateTime dtCurrent = DateTime.Now;

            //Find Time Difference details between current date and your given date
            TimeSpan tsDiff = dtCurrent.Subtract(dtYourDate);

            //Add Total Minutes for Days difference
            lTotalMinutesElapsed = lTotalMinutesElapsed + tsDiff.Days * (24 * 60);

            //Add Total Minutes for Hour difference
            lTotalMinutesElapsed = lTotalMinutesElapsed + tsDiff.Hours * 60;

            //Add Minutes 
            lTotalMinutesElapsed = lTotalMinutesElapsed + tsDiff.Minutes;

            return lTotalMinutesElapsed;
        }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you involve DateTime.Now ? And `ToString()` and `Parse()` cancel each other out...  Sorry, but this is a horrible solution to a simple problem.